# JQuery code to disable input field with a check box not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to disable the price input field when the checkbox is ticked and remove any text. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here..

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#confP').change(function(){
        if ($('#confP').is(':checked') == true){
            $('#price').val('').prop('disabled', true);
            console.log('checked');
        } else {
            $('#price').prop('disabled', false);
            console.log('unchecked');
        }
    });
</script>

<input type="checkbox" id="confP" name="confP" value="productType"?>Configurable Product?

Price <input type="text" id="price" name="price"/>
```

Comment: You forgot document ready

Comment: Your code working correctly. Try this one http://jsfiddle.net/2s7Kr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify your script content in `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#confP').change(function(){
        if ($('#confP').is(':checked') == true){
            $('#price').val('').prop('disabled', true);
            console.log('checked');
        } else {
            $('#price').prop('disabled', false);
            console.log('unchecked');
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: The example on JQuery.com for change() doesn't have this, why must I use it to make it work?

Comment: because it make sure that the page is loaded and document is ready. So $('#confP') will be able to find the element and bind the event. You can try to placing debugger; before that line and see in case of without document.ready it wont find the element #confP so it wont be able to bind the event.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,you missed `$( document ).ready(function() {` 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/943Jy/2/)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#confP').change(function(){
        if ($('#confP').is(':checked') == true){
            $('#price').val('').prop('disabled', true);
            console.log('checked');
        } else {
            $('#price').prop('disabled', false);
            console.log('unchecked');
        }
    });
 });
</script>

<input type="checkbox" id="confP" name="confP" value="productType"?>Configurable Product?

Price <input type="text" id="price" name="price"/>
```

Comment: The example on JQuery.com for change() doesn't have this, why must I use it to make it work?

Answer (score -1):

Use this to disable:

```
$('#price').attr('disabled', true);
```

And this to enable later:

```
$('#price').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Cheers.